# How to show that set is measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is the standard topological space. And $\mathbb{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra from this space.

Define set A as:

$$A = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : x = q_1 \sqrt{n_1} + q_2 \sqrt{n_2} \text{ for some } q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb{Q} , \text{ and } n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

How can I show that the set A belongs to $\mathbb{B}$?

Comment: Isn't it countable?

Comment: @Ilya What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, every $\sigma$-algebra (in particular $\mathbb B$) is closed under countable union. Moreover, every singleton set $\{x\}\subset \mathbb R$ belongs to $\mathbb B$, since $\{x\}$ is a closed set and a closed set is Borel. Consequently
$$
A=\bigcup_{q_1,q_2\in \mathbb Q,\ n_1,n_2\in\mathbb N}\{q_1\sqrt{n_1}+q_2\sqrt{n_2}\}
$$
is a countable union of sets in $\mathbb B$, and thus also belongs to $\mathbb B$.

Comment: I understand that singleton set belongs to $\mathbb{B}$. But I'm not sure about next results. Doesn't I need to prove that $B = \{x : x = a + b , a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ belongs to $\mathbb{B}$?. I mean... the set of the sum of real numbers are measurable?

Comment: The fact I am using is that the set of quadruples $(q_1,q_2,n_1,n_2)\in \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q\times \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ is countable. Since it is countable, the union appearing in my solution is a countable union. This is in contrast to your example, where you have an uncountable union (since $\mathbb R$ is uncountable). The definition of a $\sigma$-algebra is that it is closed under countable unions such as the one I have written. There is no auxiliary fact to prove.